# What is the best way to solve an equation of the form $(f(x))^2-a(f(x))+b=x$?

Tags: functions, contest-math, factoring

On a math contest I was told to solve the equation $$(x^2-3x+1)^2-3(x^2-3x+1)+1=x$$

For this particular problem I simplified by letting     $$a\equiv x^2-3x+1$$

Then I continued with $$a^2-3a+1-x=0$$
$$a=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-4\left(1-x\right)}}{2}$$
$$3\pm\sqrt{5+4x}=2a=2x^2-6x+2$$
$$\pm\sqrt{5+4x}=2x^2-6x-1$$
 I am not sure how to finish off this problem. Also, I have seen a bunch of problems like this in the past. What is the best way to approach a problem like this and also how could I finish solving this problem? Could someone also explain why f(f(x))=x has the same solutions as f(x)=x.

Comment: Is there a difference between $X$ and $x$ or is $X=x$?

Comment: Sorry, I am not that good at formatting here. Yes X=x.

Comment: *Where* do you have to look for solutions? E.g. is a solution supposed to be integer, real, complex, something entirely different...

Comment: The question just ask to solve the equation. I assume for real values of x.

Comment: Also... where did the quartic term end up in your last equation? Squaring the penultimate equation gives a quartic equation with a very nice [set of solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282x%5E2+-+6x+-1%29%5E2-5-4x)...

Comment: @Jonathan - regarding your last question: The solution set of $f(x) = x$ is contained in the solution set for $f(f(x)) = x$ but it is not the same. For example for $f(x) = 4x(1-x)$, the first equation has two real solutions and the second one has two more, all in the interval $(0,1)$. You can check this with a plot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add $x^2-3x+1$ to both sides, giving
$$(x^2-3x+1)^2 - 2(x^2-3x+1) + 1 = x + x^2-3x+1 = x^2-2x+1,$$
or
$$((x^2-3x+1)-1)^2 = (x-1)^2.$$
Thus $(x^2-3x+1)-1 = \pm (x-1)$.  The plus sign gives
$$x^2-4x+1=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad x = 2\pm\sqrt{3}.$$
The minus sign gives
$$x^2-2x-1=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad x = 1\pm\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Welcome to the club of the victims of downvoters ! Be sure that no one will comment. $+1$ for your answer. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not the first time. I keep hoping for a different result :)

Comment: Same for me and for many, many of us !

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = x^2-3x+1$.

#### Idea

The important observation here is following: If you have a solution $a$ that satisfies $f(a) = a$ then obviously
$a$ also solves the original equation because $f(f(a)) = f(a) = a$.

Finding the $a$ that solve $f(a) = a$ is easy, that is just a quadratic equation. This means you can divide $f(f(x))-x$ by $(x-a)$ for both solutions $a$ and you get a quadratic equation in $x$ which again can be solved easily.

#### Calculations

So lets first solve $f(x) = x$ This is aequivalent to $0 = x^2-4x+1$ which has the solutions $x_{1,2} = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}$

Now we can divide $f(f(x))-x$ by $(x-x_1)$ and $(x-x_2)$ or combined by $(x-x_1)(x-x_2) = x^2-4x+1 $.

Via polynomial division we get $$(f(f(x))-1)/(x^2-4x+1) = x^2-2x+1$$

Remember taht  $f(f(x))-x = 0$ is equivalent now to

$0=f(f(x))-x=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x^2-2x+1) = f(f(x))-x$.

As $x^2-2x+1$ has the zeros $x_{3,4} = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$ we can further factorize

$0=f(f(x))-x=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)$ and we have all four solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, this is a quartic equation of the form $f(f(x)) - x = 0$ where $f$ is a polynomial. Then the factor $f(x) - x$ must divide the expression $f(f(x)) - x$. This will allow you to factor the quartic term into two quadratic terms both of which can be factored using the usual formula. In this particular case, $f(x) - x = x^2-4x+1$ and you can write
$$
f(f(x)) - x = (x^2-3x+1)^2 - 3 (x^2-3x+1) + 1 - x = (x^2-4x+1)(x^2-2x-1)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The question is about $f(x)=x^2-3x+1$, and solutions to $f(f(x))=x$.
Two solutions to $f(f(x))=x$ are the solutions to $f(x)=x$.
I'm not sure why you get a cubic instead of a quartic polynomial.

Comment: You're right. I actually made a mistake expanding. I will fix it.

Comment: Why are the solutions to f(f(x))=x the same as f(x)=x?

Comment: Because, if $f(x)=x$, then $f({\color{red}{f(x)}})=f({\color{red} {x}})=x$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: simplifying and factorizing the given equation we have to solve
$$\left( {x}^{2}-4\,x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}-2\,x-1 \right) =0$$
it is easy now

Comment: How did you come to this factorization?

Comment: @Jonathan. This is magics !

Comment: but for the $-1$ thousend of thanks